# Where is TCP file on linux

Tags: linux, tcp

I am familiar with TCP-IP. I read about it in networking books. I know how TCP works. Also I know that a variety of TCP exist like reno, new reno and taho. But now I want to see the source code of them. For example how TCP works on **ubuntu 14.04**. Can any one tell me where its file is?

Comment: To clarify, you're asking for the location of the source code that handles TCP in ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: yes thanks. and some so general description to start learning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TCP is defined in the Linux Kernel. You can browse the source on [LXR](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/)

Here's the source for [/net/ipv4/tcp.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp.c)

Answer (score 2):

You will probably need to read on How to Compile Linux Kernel:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile

and then, having the source downloaded, you can modify for your needs or just observe it in somewhere like `usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-38/net/ipv4`

and you will find there the tcp source beginning from something like:

`/*
 * INET     An implementation of the TCP/IP protocol suite for the LINUX
 *      operating system.  INET is implemented using the  BSD Socket
 *      interface as the means of communication with the user level.
 *
 *      Implementation of the Transmission Control Protocol(TCP).
 *
 * Authors: Ross Biro
 *      Fred N. van Kempen, <waltje@uWalt.NL.Mugnet.ORG>
 *      Mark Evans, <evansmp@uhura.aston.ac.uk>
 *      Corey Minyard <wf-rch!minyard@relay.EU.net>
 *      Florian La Roche, <flla@stud.uni-sb.de>
 *      Charles Hedrick, <hedrick@klinzhai.rutgers.edu>
 *      Linus Torvalds, <torvalds@cs.helsinki.fi>
 *      Alan Cox, <gw4pts@gw4pts.ampr.org>
 *      Matthew Dillon, <dillon@apollo.west.oic.com>
 *      Arnt Gulbrandsen, <agulbra@nvg.unit.no>
 *      Jorge Cwik, <jorge@laser.satlink.net>`